# Мат. Ожидание. Олимпиадное задание

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Попалась задача на вероятности. Вот условие:

> Самолет героев потерпел крушение, и они оказались острове. Героям повезло: уцелела карта полетов, которая была у пилотов. По этой карте они смогли определить, какие рейсы пролетают на достаточно близком расстоянии, чтобы их сигнальные костры были замечены. Среди героев оказался профессор , которого заинтересовал вопрос: какое математическое ожидание времени ожидания первого пролетающего мимо самолета.
>
> В рамках этой задачи он использовал следующие ограничения: Есть
>   набор-авиа рейсов.
>
> - все авиарейсы независимы;
> - интервалы вылета одного маршрута постоянны;
> - все маршруты начинают движения в произвольное время, до того как они потерпели крушение.
>
> Другими словами, если k-ый авиарейс летает с интервалом tk часов и
>   первый раз после крушения он пролетит мимо через sk часов, то sk —
>   случайная величина равномерно распределенная на полуинтервале `[0;  
>   tk)`.
>
> **Формат ввода:**    Первая строка входных данных содержит единственное число N — количество маршрутов (1 ≤N ≤5).
>
> Вторая строка содержит N целых положительных чисел tk (1≤tk≤50).
>
> **Формат вывода:**    В единственной строке выведите математическое ожидание времени ожидания первого самолета в виде несократимой дроби
>   (в часах).
>
> **Пример ввода и вывода:**
>
> ```
> 2
>
> 2 2
>
> Ответ - 2/3
> ```

Comment: "после крушения" - where did they bury the survivors?

Comment: просто к задаче была длинная преамбула про крушение самолетов и про то, как на острове оказались выжившие.
Думаю, контекст излишен

Comment: Условие непонятно...

Comment: Поправил условие. Теперь все так, как было на мероприятии

Comment: а в чём вы видите проблему? N = 5 за N!*N есть простое решение. Вот если бы 100.000 было тогда да, думать пришлось бы.

Comment: А не могли бы вы привести алгоритм такого решения. Или объяснить теоретический материал этой темы?

Comment: 1 < 2 <--- T(1) <= T(2) ---> Всего пространство исходов = 2*2 = 4 (размерность не спрашивайте) Integrate[ 2 - x,{x,0,2} ] = 2x - x*x/2 | 0,2 = 4 - 2 = 2 --> 2/4 = 1/2 вероятность того что 1 прилетит раньше 2(и так было понятно, но для примера расчётов). Аналогично 1/2 что 2 раньше 1.

Теперь для 1 случая. M = Integrate[ x*[(2-x)/2] , {x,0,2}] = (x*x/2 - x*x*x/6)|0,2 = 4/2 - 8/6 = 4/6 = 2/3. * На вероятность = 1/2. Для 2 случая аналогично. Итого Ответ: (2/3)*(1/2) * 2 = 2/3.

Почитать - определение мат ожидания и простейшие интегралы. Это если точное мат решение.

Comment: кто-то может это ответом выразить, так чтобы понятно было?

Comment: Алгоритм - переберём 1 самолёт, который прилетит, и вычислим все интегралы от него. Сложность - N*N.

Answer (score -1):

Для одного рейса:

1) время ожидания не больше t<sub>k</sub>;
2) вероятность появления за время t (отношение временных интервалов):
 p<sub>k</sub>(t) = t / t<sub>k</sub>;
3) вероятность непоявления за время t (противоположное событие):
q<sub>k</sub>(t) = 1 - p<sub>k</sub>(t) = (t - t<sub>k</sub>) / t<sub>k</sub>.

Для задачи в целом:
1) время ожидания не больше min<sub>k</sub> {t<sub>k</sub>};
2) вероятность непоявления за время t равна произведению соответствующих  вероятностей (т.к. эти события независимые):
Q(t) = ∏<sub>k</sub> q<sub>k</sub>(t) = ∏<sub>k</sub> (t - t<sub>k</sub>) / t<sub>k</sub>;
3) вероятность появления за время t (противоположное событие): P(t) = 1-Q(t),

P(t) = 1 - ∏<sub>k</sub> (t - t<sub>k</sub>) / t<sub>k</sub>;  .

Answer (score -1):

чтобы самолёт прилетел первый во время tk надо чтоб он не прилетел раньше и другие самолёты не прилетели раньше него

если `то sk — случайная величина равномерно распределенная на полуинтервале [0;   tk). то`  величина `pk(t) = t/tk * (интеграл от 0 до tk по tt (1-t)*dt/tk) - (N-1)* тот же интеграл`